# How to troubleshoot frequent WiFi disconnection from MiFi router?

Tags: wireless-networking, mifi, connection

[image]

I recently upgraded from a HUAWEI E153 USB modem to a [E583C mobile WiFi router](http://www.huaweidevice.com/worldwide/productFeatures.do?pinfoId=3093&directoryId=5009&treeId=3619&tab=0).

The device grants my other devices Internet access through wifi perfectly, until I get located in my present office. Between five to thirty minutes, my dependent computers will lose wifi connection.

Attempting to reconnect will fail. Any new devices attempting to register its wifi network will *also fail*. It would take a really long time before it can "recover" and the wifi adapters can pick up the connection and regain Internet access. I am forced to plug in the USB cable to maintain a wired network connection instead.

My colleague has a similar mifi model, HUAWEI E5830, which she experiences the exact same problem - fine outside, guaranteed disconnection in the office.

First guess is there are too many other wifi access points in the building, so I tried switching around the transmission channels 1, 6, 11, and even 13 but none had better results. In expanding Windows network diagnostic logs it shows there are around 19 networks in the area, so I am guessing the interference is so great there is no way my little mifi device can compete. *Even if I attach the extended antenna.*

Below is the diagnostic log which I am unable to properly identify what I can do to further troubleshoot and possibly solve the problem in this office area?

```
Windows Network Diagnostics Publisher details 

Issues found 
Problem with wireless adapter or access pointProblem with wireless adapter or access point Detected  
Reset the wireless adapter Not run 
Investigate router or access point issues Not run 
Refer to Windows Help and Support for more information about wireless connectivity problems Not run 


Issues found Detection details 

6 Problem with wireless adapter or access point Detected  

Reset the wireless adapter Not run 

Investigate router or access point issues Not run 

If you're connected to a hotspot or domain network, contact the network administrator. Otherwise: 1. Unplug or turn off the device. 2. After all the lights on the device are off, wait at least 10 seconds. 3. Turn the device back on or plug it back into the power outlet. To restart a router or access point that has a built-in battery, press and quickly release the Reset button. 
Refer to Windows Help and Support for more information about wireless connectivity problems Not run 

Windows cannot resolve your wireless connectivity issue. 


Detection details  

Diagnostics Information (Network Adapter) 
Details about network adapter diagnosis: 

Network adapter Wireless Network Connection driver information:

   Description . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Centrino(R) Ultimate-N 6300 AGN
   Manufacturer  . . . . . . . . . : Intel Corporation
   Provider  . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel
   Version   . . . . . . . . . . . : 13.0.0.107
   Inf File Name . . . . . . . . . : C:\Windows\INF\oem20.inf
   Inf File Date . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, November 29, 2009  8:53:22 AM
   Section Name  . . . . . . . . . : Install_MPCIEX_Dell_6300_AGN_3x3_HMC_WIN7_64_MOW
   Hardware ID . . . . . . . . . . : pci\ven_8086&dev_422b&subsys_11218086
   Instance Status Flags . . . . . : 0x180200a
   Device Manager Status Code  . . : 0
   IfType  . . . . . . . . . . . . : 71
   Physical Media Type . . . . . . : 9



Diagnostics Information (Wireless Connectivity) 
Details about wireless connectivity diagnosis: 

Information for connection being diagnosed
 Interface GUID: 2e86690b-af98-44fd-bce9-af109040338a
 Interface name: Intel(R) Centrino(R) Ultimate-N 6300 AGN
 Interface type: Native WiFi
 Profile: MYWIFI
 SSID: MYWIFI
 SSID length: 9
 Connection mode: Infra
 Security: Yes
 Connect even if network is not broadcasting: No

Connection incident diagnosed
 Auto Configuration ID: 148
 Connection ID: 164

Connection status summary
 Connection started at: 2011-08-12 19:11:44-685
 Profile match: Success
 Pre-Association: Success
 Association: Success
 Security and Authentication: Fail

List of visible access point(s): 19 item(s) total, 19 item(s) displayed
        BSSID       BSS Type PHY    Signal(dB)  Chnl/freq    SSID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
FE-FF-6F-40-07-3E   Ad hoc   b  -70     10   A9F1BDF1DAB1NVT4F4F59
F4-C7-14-8A-58-71   Infra    g  -45     6    MYWIFI
54-E6-FC-A5-09-CA   Infra    g  -89     11   AP2A
00-0B-85-87-5D-CF   Infra    g  -89     6    Wireless@SG
00-1E-4A-32-1B-D0   Infra    g  -88     6    (Unnamed Network)
00-0B-85-87-5D-CD   Infra    g  -88     6    (Unnamed Network)
00-1D-70-F2-55-70   Infra    g  -74     6    (Unnamed Network)
30-46-9A-8E-AA-DA   Infra    g  -84     6    (Unnamed Network)
00-0B-85-87-5D-CC   Infra    g  -89     6    Wireless@SGx
00-24-C4-2F-12-B0   Infra    g  -85     6    (Unnamed Network)
00-27-19-D5-1D-DA   Infra    g  -89     7    AP1
00-1E-4A-32-16-F0   Infra    g  -70     1    (Unnamed Network)
00-1E-13-84-FA-10   Infra    g  -61     1    (Unnamed Network)
54-E6-FC-E5-54-26   Infra    <unknown>  -91     3    AP2B
00-1E-4A-32-26-E0   Infra    g  -46     1    (Unnamed Network)
00-1E-4A-32-1D-A0   Infra    g  -81     11   (Unnamed Network)
00-1E-13-85-06-70   Infra    g  -88     11   (Unnamed Network)
AE-80-83-1F-76-D1   Ad hoc   g  -91     4    Free Public WiFi
00-0B-85-91-6C-2F   Infra    g  -92     1    Wireless@SG

Connection History

 Information for Auto Configuration ID 149

  List of visible networks: 11 item(s) total, 11 item(s) displayed
  BSS Type PHY  Security    Signal(RSSI)    Compatible  SSID
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Ad hoc     b  Yes     50  Yes     A9F1BDF1DAB1NVT4F4F59
  Infra  g  Yes     93  Yes     MYWIFI
  Infra  g  Yes     18  Yes     AP2A
  Infra  g  No      18  Yes     Wireless@SG
  Infra  g  Yes     91  Yes     (Unnamed Network)
  Infra  g  No      20  Yes     (Unnamed Network)
  Infra  g  No      26  Yes     (Unnamed Network)
  Infra  g  Yes     18  Yes     Wireless@SGx
  Infra  g  Yes     18  Yes     AP1
  Infra  <unknown>  Yes     16  Yes     AP2B
  Ad hoc     g  No      15  Yes     Free Public WiFi

  List of preferred networks: 2 item(s)
   Profile: MYWIFI
    SSID: MYWIFI
    SSID length: 9
    Connection mode: Infra
    Security: Yes
    Set by group policy: No
    Connect even if network is not broadcasting: No
    Connectable: Yes
   Profile: icelava
    SSID: icelava
    SSID length: 7
    Connection mode: Infra
    Security: Yes
    Set by group policy: No
    Connect even if network is not broadcasting: No
    Connectable: No
     Reason: 0x00028002

 Information for Connection ID 165
 Connection started at: 2011-08-12 19:12:36-457
  Auto Configuration ID: 149
  Profile: MYWIFI
  SSID: MYWIFI
  SSID length: 9
  Connection mode: Infra
  Security: Yes
  Pre-Association and Association
   Connectivity settings provided by hardware manufacturer (IHV): No
   Security settings provided by hardware manufacturer (IHV): No
   Profile matches network requirements: Success
   Pre-association status: Success
   Association status: Success
    Last AP:  f4-c7-14-8a-58-71
  Security and Authentication
   Configured security type: WPA-PSK
   Configured encryption type: CCMP(AES)
   802.1X protocol: No
   Key exchange initiated: Yes
    Unicast key received: Yes
    Multicast key received: No
   Number of security packets received: 8
   Number of security packets sent: 8
   Security attempt status: Success

 Information for Auto Configuration ID 148

  List of visible networks: 12 item(s) total, 12 item(s) displayed
  BSS Type PHY  Security    Signal(RSSI)    Compatible  SSID
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Ad hoc     b  Yes     50  Yes     A9F1BDF1DAB1NVT4F4F59
  Infra  g  Yes     93  Yes     MYWIFI
  Infra  g  Yes     16  Yes     AP2A
  Infra  g  No      18  Yes     Wireless@SG
  Infra  g  Yes     90  Yes     (Unnamed Network)
  Infra  g  No      18  Yes     (Unnamed Network)
  Infra  g  No      26  Yes     (Unnamed Network)
  Infra  g  Yes     20  Yes     Wireless@SGx
  Infra  g  Yes     20  Yes     AP1
  Infra  <unknown>  Yes     16  Yes     AP2B
  Infra  <unknown>  Yes     16  Yes     sandy
  Ad hoc     g  No      15  Yes     Free Public WiFi

  List of preferred networks: 2 item(s)
   Profile: MYWIFI
    SSID: MYWIFI
    SSID length: 9
    Connection mode: Infra
    Security: Yes
    Set by group policy: No
    Connect even if network is not broadcasting: No
    Connectable: No
     Reason: 0x00028006
   Profile: icelava
    SSID: icelava
    SSID length: 7
    Connection mode: Infra
    Security: Yes
    Set by group policy: No
    Connect even if network is not broadcasting: No
    Connectable: No
     Reason: 0x00028002

 Information for Connection ID 164
 Connection started at: 2011-08-12 19:11:44-685
  Auto Configuration ID: 148
  Profile: MYWIFI
  SSID: MYWIFI
  SSID length: 9
  Connection mode: Infra
  Security: Yes
  Pre-Association and Association
   Connectivity settings provided by hardware manufacturer (IHV): No
   Security settings provided by hardware manufacturer (IHV): No
   Profile matches network requirements: Success
   Pre-association status: Success
   Association status: Success
    Last AP:  f4-c7-14-8a-58-71
  Security and Authentication
   Configured security type: WPA-PSK
   Configured encryption type: CCMP(AES)
   802.1X protocol: No
   Key exchange initiated: Yes
    Unicast key received: Yes
    Multicast key received: No
   Number of security packets received: 30
   Number of security packets sent: 30
   Security attempt status: Fail 0x00038012

 Information for Connection ID 163
 Connection started at: 2011-08-12 19:09:58-699
  Auto Configuration ID: 148
  Profile: MYWIFI
  SSID: MYWIFI
  SSID length: 9
  Connection mode: Infra
  Security: Yes
  Pre-Association and Association
   Connectivity settings provided by hardware manufacturer (IHV): No
   Security settings provided by hardware manufacturer (IHV): No
   Profile matches network requirements: Success
   Pre-association status: Success
   Association status: Success
    Last AP:  f4-c7-14-8a-58-71
  Security and Authentication
   Configured security type: WPA-PSK
   Configured encryption type: CCMP(AES)
   802.1X protocol: No
   Key exchange initiated: Yes
    Unicast key received: Yes
    Multicast key received: No
   Number of security packets received: 30
   Number of security packets sent: 30
   Security attempt status: Fail 0x00038012

 Information for Auto Configuration ID 147

  List of visible networks: 11 item(s) total, 11 item(s) displayed
  BSS Type PHY  Security    Signal(RSSI)    Compatible  SSID
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Ad hoc     b  Yes     51  Yes     A9F1BDF1DAB1NVT4F4F59
  Infra  g  Yes     95  Yes     MYWIFI
  Infra  g  Yes     20  Yes     AP2A
  Infra  g  No      23  Yes     Wireless@SG
  Infra  g  Yes     91  Yes     (Unnamed Network)
  Infra  g  No      23  Yes     (Unnamed Network)
  Infra  g  No      26  Yes     (Unnamed Network)
  Infra  g  Yes     21  Yes     Wireless@SGx
  Infra  g  Yes     23  Yes     AP1
  Infra  <unknown>  Yes     13  Yes     AP2B
  Infra  <unknown>  Yes     13  Yes     sandy

  List of preferred networks: 2 item(s)
   Profile: MYWIFI
    SSID: MYWIFI
    SSID length: 9
    Connection mode: Infra
    Security: Yes
    Set by group policy: No
    Connect even if network is not broadcasting: No
    Connectable: No
     Reason: 0x00028006
   Profile: icelava
    SSID: icelava
    SSID length: 7
    Connection mode: Infra
    Security: Yes
    Set by group policy: No
    Connect even if network is not broadcasting: No
    Connectable: No
     Reason: 0x00028002

 Information for Connection ID 162
 Connection started at: 2011-08-12 19:08:47-704
  Auto Configuration ID: 147
  Profile: MYWIFI
  SSID: MYWIFI
  SSID length: 9
  Connection mode: Infra
  Security: Yes
  Pre-Association and Association
   Connectivity settings provi


Diagnostics Information (Wireless Connectivity) 
Details about wireless connectivity diagnosis: 

For complete information about this session see the wireless connectivity information event.

Helper Class: Auto Configuration
 Initialize status: Success

Information for connection being diagnosed
 Interface GUID: 2e86690b-af98-44fd-bce9-af109040338a
 Interface name: Intel(R) Centrino(R) Ultimate-N 6300 AGN
 Interface type: Native WiFi
 Profile: MYWIFI
 SSID: MYWIFI
 SSID length: 9
 Connection mode: Infra
 Security: Yes
 Connect even if network is not broadcasting: No

Result of diagnosis: Problem found
 Issue referred to: L2Sec Helper Class

Root cause:
Windows could not connect to "MYWIFI"
You can try to connect again.

Repair option:
Try connecting to "MYWIFI" again, or connect to a different network
If you still can't connect to the network and you are the administrator, turn off your wireless router or access point, wait at least 10 seconds, turn it back on, and then try connecting again.




Diagnostics Information (L2sec Helper Class) 
Details about L2Sec Helper Class diagnosis: 

For complete information about this session see the Wireless Diagnostic Informational Event.

Helper Class: Layer2 Security
 Initialize Status: Success

Result of diagnosis: There may be a problem

Information for connection being diagnosed
 Interface GUID: {2e86690b-af98-44fd-bce9-af109040338a}
 Interface name: Intel(R) Centrino(R) Ultimate-N 6300 AGN
 Interface type: Native WiFi
 Profile: MYWIFI
 SSID: MYWIFI
 SSID length: 9
 Connection mode: Infra
 Security enabled: Yes
 Connection ID: 164
 Security settings provided by hardware manufacturer (IHV): No
 Profile matches network requirements: Yes
 Pre-Association and association status: Success
 Security and Authentication:
  Configured security type: Wireless Protected Access with pre-shared keys (WPA-PSK)
  Configured Encryption type: CCMP (AES)
  Security connect status: Fail 0x00038012
  Number of security packets received: 30
  Number of security packets sent: 30
  802.1X protocol: No
  Key exchange initiated: Yes
   Unicast keys received: Yes
   Multicast keys received: No



Network Diagnostics Log 
File Name:  37A4332C-446B-4077-B61F-5E9434B7DA60.Diagnose.0.etl 

Collection information 
Computer Name:  MYLAPTOP 
Windows Version: 6.1 
Architecture: amd64 
Time: Friday, August 12, 2011 7:12:44 PM 

Publisher details  

Windows Network Diagnostics 
Detects problems with network connectivity. 
Package Version: 1.0 
Publisher: Microsoft Windows
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok while this does not solve the issue in general, specifically in my case, my colleague informed there is a Wireless Intrusion Prevention System (WIPS) in the building - it will *jam* unregistered wireless access points that appear within range.